# Directory Permission Order

Tags: files, permissions, group

In Linux, let us assume we have a directory with the following properties:

```
drwx---r-x 29 user1      group1 4096 Jun 22 14:11 dir1
```

can I, as `user2` having group `group1`, navigate into `dir1`?

Since `other` has `r` and `x` permissions, I was thinking I could, but I could not navigate into the directory and got the following error:

```
-bash: cd: dir1/: Permission denied
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions for *group* take priority over permissions for *other*. And in turn, permissions for *user* take priority over both. You're not the owner but you are in `group1`, so those are the permissions that are checked.

Generally, permissions rarely become less restrictive when going from *user* to *group* to *other*. In your scenario, if you want members of `group1` to have the same access to this file as everyone else you need to give them the same permissions: `rwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks. Is there anything I could do except for changing permissions of the directory or group of `user2`?

Comment: @BatuhanTasdoven I've updated the answer; hopefully this is clearer for you